# Oblivion Ring targeting an Aura

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Suppose I cast [Oblivion Ring](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?printed=true&multiverseid=234567) and have it target the [Pacifism](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=228956) which is encumbering one of my creatures. What happens if the Oblivion Ring is subsequently destroyed?

1. Pacifism re-enters play enchanting the same creature as before
2. Pacifism chooses a new target when it re-enters play
3. Nothing -- Auras can only exist while enchanting a creature, so Pacifism disappears in a poof of smoke when it's exiled, similar to what tokens do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [rulings on this card's gatherer entry](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=234567)

> 01/10/2008 If the exiled card is an Aura, that card's owner chooses what it will enchant as it comes back onto the battlefield. An Aura put onto the battlefield this way doesn't target anything, but the Aura's enchant ability restricts what it can be attached to. If the Aura can't legally be attached to anything, it remains exiled forever.

It would appear that option 2 in your question is the correct interpretation.

Comment: I didn't notice that there was a ruling on exactly this question :). Two interesting points: the Aura "doesn't target anything" when it re-enters the battlefield, meaning that you could attach it to a creature with prot white or hexproof, and if it can't legally attach to anything it *remains exiled* rather than simply going to the graveyard.

Comment: @JSBᾶngs Yes, "doesn't target anything" when it re-enters has an interesting implication, but I believe that protection from white prevents it from being attached ... there's a hair to split there on hexproof, that would require looking at the comprehensive rules regarding "attach" :)

Comment: I think you're right about prot white. My reasoning is that a creature that gains protection immediately sheds any relevant auras that it has, so protection is a state-based effect that doesn't just affect targeting. I'm looking through the comprehensive rules now, though.

Comment: Ok, here's the rule: *702.15c  A permanent or player with protection can't be enchanted by Auras that have the stated quality. Such Auras attached to the permanent or player with protection will be put into their owners' graveyards as a state-based action. (See rule 704, "State-Based Actions.")*. So you could attach it to a creature with prot white, but it would immediately go into the graveyard as a state-based effect.

Comment: @Stephen: attaching isn't inherently targeted, I'm pretty sure, so you could attach it to a creature with hexproof or shroud.

Comment: You cannot bring it in and attach it to a pro white creature to make it fall off and go to your GY.  (perhaps so you can get it back with Auramancer.)  If the only creature(s) on the field when the O-ring leaves have pro-white, the Pacifism will remain in exile.  See rule 303.4g